# HTML Get URL parameter

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I want to change url without reload the page because Im using AJAX function to reload a div.
The problem is that when the AJAX load the div, **it doesn't read the url parameter**.

My code (I've already load the jquery.js etc.) :

**index.php**

```
<a href="#page=1" onClick='refresh()'> Link </a>
<a href="#page=2" onClick='refresh()'> Link2 </a>


<script type="text/javascript">

 $.ajaxSetup ({
    cache: false
 });

 function refresh() {

    $("#test").load("mypage.php"); //Refresh
}

</script>



<div id="test">

</div>
```

**mypage.php**

```
 <?php 

 if (isset($_GET['page'])){

   $page = $_GET['page'];
 }
echo $page;

?>
```

Comment: You can pass parameters in the load function. `$("#test").load("mypage.php");` becomes `$("#test").load("mypage.php?page=mypage");`

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do. Can you explain a bit better?

Comment: @putvande, it's a exemple, my real code is too much bigger, I want load all my website's pages only using AJAX

Comment: Maybe what you are looking for is the HTML5 history API. Have a look at that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Getting after `#` hash tag:

#### With PHP (Required page load)

[parse_url()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) `fragment` index thats you need

```
$url = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$url["fragment"]; //This variable contains the fragment
```

#### With jQuery: (Not required page load)

```
var hash = $(this).attr('href').split('#')[1];
var hash = $(this).attr('href').match(/#(.*$)/)[1];
```

## Demo (Used without hash tag)

#### index.php

```
<a href="#" class="myLink" data-id="1"> Link </a> | <a href="#" class="myLink"  data-id="2"> Link2 </a>

<script type="text/javascript">
 $(".myLink").click(function(e) { // when click myLink class
    e.preventDefault(); // Do nothing
    var pageId = $(this).attr('data-id'); // get page id from setted data-id tag
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'mypage.php', // post to file
        data: { id: pageId}, // post data id
        success:function(response){ 
            $("#test").html(response); // write into div on success function
        }
    });
});
</script>

<div id="test"></div>
```

#### mypage.php

```
<?php 
// get with $_POST['id']
echo "Loaded Page ID: ".($_POST['id'] ? $_POST['id'] : "FAILED");
?>
```

Comment: can you show me an exemple of use (for jQuery), because I don't know what to do with the jQuery code.

Comment: @user2372006 sorry for late.. Im busy yesterday.. Added demo code. I did make it without hash tag.

Answer (score 1):

PHP can't read the fragment without reloading the page. This can be done using JS.

Below the script I use to read the parameter values without reloading the page. I don't think it's the best method there is, as there are plugins you could use to do the same (and much more), but it works. I found it online some time ago, but unfortunately I don't remember where :(

```
var urlParams;
(window.onpopstate = function () {
    var match,
        pl     = /\+/g,  // Regex for replacing addition symbol with a space
        search = /([^&=]+)=?([^&]*)/g,
        decode = function (s) { return decodeURIComponent(s.replace(pl, " ")); },
        query  = window.location.hash.slice(1);
    urlParams = {};
    while (match = search.exec(query)) {
       urlParams[decode(match[1])] = decode(match[2]);
    }
})();
```

You would then get the parameter value with:

```
urlParams['page']
```

If you will work a lot with hash urls, you should check out this plugin: http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-bbq-plugin/

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a `page` parameter to the URL you're requesting.

Try this:

```
<a href="#page=1" onClick='refresh(1)'> Link </a>
<a href="#page=2" onClick='refresh(2)'> Link2 </a>


<script type="text/javascript">

 $.ajaxSetup ({
    cache: false
 });

 function refresh(pageNumber) {

    $("#test").load("mypage.php?page="+pageNumber); //Refresh
}

</script>
```

Comment: load works but, the problem is that I can't send a link of my current position on the website to someone by this way. that's why I want that the paramater show themselve on the URL BAR.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible for you to pass parameters through the [load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) function in jQuery.

There are 2 common ways of doing so:

Using get:

JS:

```
$('#test').load('mypage.php?page=mypage');
```

PHP:

```
<?php

if (isset($_GET['page']))
{
    $page = $_GET['page'];
}
echo $page;

?>
```

Or using data as a post:

JS:

```
$('#test').load('mypage.php', { page: mypage });
```

PHP:

```
if (isset($_POST['page']))
{
    $page = $_POST['page'];
}
echo $page;

?>
```

Comment: I don't want POST, and passing parameter in the load works but, the problem is that I can't send a link of my current position on the website to someone by this way. that's why I want that the paramater show themselve on the URL BAR.

Comment: Then you should look at Bora's answer. :)